# I'm getting 'module' object is not callable error when i try to run my code

Tags: python, pycharm, generative-adversarial-network

```
def define_discriminator(in_shape=(100, 100, 3)):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', input_shape=in_shape))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    opt = adam_v2(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

but in the end i keep getting -
*in define_discriminator

```
    opt = adam_v2(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable*
```

someone please help me out with this!

Comment: What is `adam_v2`?

Comment: You are calling `adam_v2` instead of importing something from there. `from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam import Adam
`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
opt = adam_v2(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
```

with

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
```